# Email states that my bounty has ended, when it clearly has not

Tags: bug, bounties, email

Something is wrong with when these emails are getting sent, I think. Perhaps a time zone, or DST bug?

[image]

I got an email at 3:02 stating that the bounty had ended (and got a notification in my SE inbox), and when I went to the page at 3:39, the bounty still had 16 minutes to go!

A minor bug, and probably not something too critical, but a bug nevertheless.

Comment: I think there's a small grace period after the bounty ends...

Comment: @Yannis that grace period is 24 hours long, not 1 hour. It says so in the email I received.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII are you sending emails to yourself from the future?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Note to self: I should tell myself the winner of this year's Super Bowl and make a ton of money!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII the Super Bowl is _next_ year...

Comment: @ColeJohnson not to my future self it isn't...

Answer (score 3):

Yannis is correct in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195644/email-states-that-my-bounty-has-ended-when-it-clearly-has-not#comment616907_195644).

There is a grace period once the bounty has ended, so one can actually *act* on the email / notice.

Comment: Why not just send it 24 hours _before_ it's ended (the grace period starts)

Comment: I understand there's a grace period and all but there must be something wrong with the timings of the emails. I received an [email](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RWWsN.png) 09/25/2013 8:55AM PDT. The actual bounty [hasn't actually expired yet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pNCob.png). It ends 09/25/2013 9:27AM PDT. The grace period hasn't even begun yet. It is misleading.

Comment: Oded is just trying to cover up that the time distortion field created by the SE servers is doing strange things again. It started with a bet, but has long since developed a life of its own.